# Command line: How to handle spaces in filenames

Tags: macos, command-line, shell, pipe

I am measuring the total sizes of a bunch of files, whose paths I have stored in a text document, files.txt. Example contents of files.txt:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

This shell command gives me the output I want:

```
$ du -hc $(cat files.txt)
```

unless I have a filename with spaces in it, e.g.: `file 9.txt` Then, `du -hc` tries to parse the file name at the space. No matter where I seem to put quotations, in files.txt or in my shell command, it still parses incorrectly. What should I do instead?

FYI, my file list document is output of a command like so:

```
find ~/Dropbox/ -type f -iname "*.BMP" >> bmpfound.txt
```

My system details: MacOS, using oh-my-zsh in Terminal.app

Comment: If you have `xargs`, try `cat files.txt|xargs -I{} du -hc "{}"`, but this will probably fail with file names with `"`. More safe maybe is to do it in a loop `while read line;do du -hc "$line";done <files.txt`

Comment: If your `du` takes arg `--files0-from` then use that and change your find to add `-print0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leverage the `-print0` option in `find` and pipe to `xargs -0`:

```
find ~/Dropbox/ -type f -iname "*.BMP" -print0 | xargs -0 du -ch
```

Alternatively, as Gordon Davisson commented, this can be simplified:

```
find ~/Dropbox/ -type f -iname "*.BMP" -exec du -ch {} +
```

Either of these should work with filenames that contain spaces, or any manner of goofy characters, for that matter.

I'm not sure if you meant to intentionally redirect `find`'s output to a file rather than piping it, but if you actually desired to keep the file list around, you could do this instead:

```
xargs -0 du -ch < bmpfound.txt
```

Comment: If you don't need to store the `find` results in a file, you can make it even simpler with `find ~/Dropbox/ -type f -iname "*.BMP" -exec du -ch {} +`

Comment: @GordonDavisson Brilliant! I had initially tried the `-exec du` route, but somehow completely missed the `+` syntax. That's very handy.